# splitViewController's willShowViewController & willHideViewController not being called after upgrade/change

Tags: xcode

I have had to rebuild my application due to an issue with xCode not archiving my current one, so I created a new project and ported all my files in and after removing some of the release and retain issues i got th eapp to work, except the following things do not fire.

They are in conjunction with a popover i set up as well that does not work:

```
  -(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController *)pc
  {
  NSLog(@"Split View Controller Landscape");

 }

 -(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
 {
  NSLog(@"Split View Controller Portable");
 }
```

Also the pop overi use a button to trigger but this also does not show:

```
 -(void)viewMenu:(id)sender{
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(10.0f, 50.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
 }
```

I am not sure that thi smight also all be out dated etc.

thanks.
PS if you need to see more code let me now

Comment: things to check:

 - the controller in which you are implementing these delegate members
   has the `<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>` in the interface
   declaration
 - the AppDelegate.m has set the .delegate (this gets auto-generated
   if you create a new project using the Master-detail template in Xcode)

Comment: thanks for the reply as it reminded me of this but I sorted this out as I have soem variables missing, and all is fine now and the app is on the store. There is now way to just check this as answered rather than add the answer i just said  as its not really an answer? Thanks by the way